# Classic ASP crash course

Tags: asp-classic

I'm a C# and PHP developer. At work, I just got some classic ASP stuff dumped in my lap. I only need to make edits for a few weeks so I don't want to have to learn too much about legacy stuff I'll never touch again. However, I do need to be able to do my job for this duration.

How can I get a good crash course in ASP? I need to get good-enough at it very quickly. What sites/books/resources would best fit this need?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com has a really good ASP tutorial. It's actually what I used when I went into classic ASP from a PHP background in school.

Answer (score 7):

realistically, classic ASP is just VBScript + a couple of libraries that handle web interaction.

The fastest way is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt.aspx

understand the basics of VBScript  (it's relatively tiny)

then understand the basic objects of classic ASP

Request
Response
Server
Session
Application
ASPError

Answer (score 4):

check out http://www.devguru.com/ and go to the vbscript section for quick references to their functions